# Consolidating Tables from multiple work sheets

Tags: arrays, vba, concatenation

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro70()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim sheets_Count As Integer
Dim sheets_Name() As String
Dim i As Integer
sheets_Count = Sheets.Count

ReDim sheets_Name(0 To sheets_Count - 1)

For i = 1 To sheets_Count
   sheets_Name(i - 1) = "'" & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name & "'!R1C1:R17C2"
Next i

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets.Add()

With ws2
    .Range("A1").Consolidate sheets_Name, xlSum, True, True, False
End With

End Sub


Sub Macro71()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim sheets_Count As Integer
Dim sheets_Name() As String
Dim i As Integer
sheets_Count = Sheets.Count

ReDim sheets_Name(0 To sheets_Count - 1)

For i = 1 To sheets_Count
   sheets_Name(i - 1) = "'" & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name & "'!R24C1:R35C2"
Next i

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets.Add()

With ws2
    .Range("A24").Consolidate sheets_Name, xlSum, True, True, False
End With

End Sub


Sub Macro72()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim sheets_Count As Integer
Dim sheets_Name() As String
Dim i As Integer
sheets_Count = Sheets.Count

ReDim sheets_Name(0 To sheets_Count - 1)

For i = 1 To sheets_Count
   sheets_Name(i - 1) = "'" & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name & "'!R39C1:R50C2"
Next i

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets.Add()

With ws2
    .Range("A39").Consolidate sheets_Name, xlSum, True, True, False
End With

End Sub
```

this works perfectly for me, but the last issue i must say is that it generates new sheet. can i have the same sheet for data to be collected into for all of these tables. 
i tried putting ws2.Name = "consolidated" for all three but it shows error. i want sub 71 and 72 to get put into the same sheet as sub 70 gets put in. and thanks heaps for helping me so much.

Comment: the error it is giving me is cannot open consolidation source file "sheets_name(i)"

Comment: I see you use sheet_Name(i) and sheets_Name(i) ... is one incorrect? Does the error say what line it is on? (please edit your question, over adding a comment.)

Comment: IT is "sheets_Name(i)"

Comment: @DavidHempy when i run the code it gives me error with this :  cannot open consolidation source file "sheets_name(i)"   although my active workbook has multiple sheets with names of sheet4, sheet4(2),sheet8, sheet9 etc

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something more like this (untested)

```
sheets_Count = Sheets.Count

ReDim sheets_Name(0 to sheets_Count-1)

For i = 1 To sheets_Count
   sheets_Name(i-1) = "'" & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name & "'!R10C1:R26C2"
Next i

Set wb = ThisWorkbook 
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets.Add()

With ws2
    .Range("A1").Consolidate sheets_Name, xlSum, True, True, False
End With
```

See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.consolidate

Here's the example from that link:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Consolidate _ 
            Sources:=Array("Sheet2!R1C1:R37C6", "Sheet3!R1C1:R37C6"), _ 
            Function:=xlSum
```

EDIT - if you want to add multiple ranges from each sheet you can try this:

```
Dim n
sheets_Count = Sheets.Count

ReDim sheets_Name(0 To (sheets_Count * 2) - 1)
n = 0
For i = 1 To sheets_Count
   sheets_Name(n) = "'" & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name & "'!R10C1:R26C2" 
   sheets_Name(n+1) = "'" & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name & "'!R40C1:R50C2"
   n = n + 2
Next i
```

Comment: i have tried it it is giving me error saying subscript out of range  point to this "

   sheets_Name(i) = "'" & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name & "'!R10C1:R26C2"

Comment: and if i were to add other ranges will i add it next to "'!R10C1:R26C2"  with commas?

Comment: I don't know if it works with multi-region ranges - you'd have to test that out.

Comment: If you want anyone to be able to read that, you should edit your question to add it (along with what error it gives you and on which line)

Comment: if i can get help on this one

Comment: yes i did and i have updated with images as what i am getting as a result if you could help me keep them separate tables it would be great help

Comment: You're trying to do too much at once - go back to one consolidation range, get that working, and then repeat for the other two consolidations, making the appropriate changes.

Comment: thanks i have tried and it works the last issue is to put them on the same worksheet.